# How do I parse a YAML file in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, yaml

I would like to know how to parse a YAML file with the following contents:

```
--- 
javascripts: 
- fo_global:
  - lazyload-min
  - holla-min
```

Currently I am trying to parse it this way:

```
@custom_asset_packages_yml = (File.exists?("#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/asset_packages.yml") ? YAML.load_file("#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/asset_packages.yml") : nil)
    if !@custom_asset_packages_yml.nil?
      @custom_asset_packages_yml['javascripts'].each{ |js|
        js['fo_global'].each{ |script|
         script
        }
      }
    end
```

But it doesn't seem to work and gives me an error that the value is nil.

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.each
```

If I try this, it puts out the entire string (fo_globallazyload-minholla-min):

```
if !@custom_asset_packages_yml.nil?
          @custom_asset_packages_yml['javascripts'].each{ |js|
            js['fo_global']
          }
        end
```

Comment: can you give the output of the script when you run it? files in the right place? you can always fire up a Rails console and see if ruby can see that path as well.

Comment: Yeah, the file does exist and is in the right location. Ive updated my post with the error.

Answer (score 522, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but why try to parse the file? Why not just load the YAML and examine the object(s) that result?

If your sample YAML is in `some.yml`, then this:

```
require 'yaml'
thing = YAML.load_file('some.yml')
puts thing.inspect
```

gives me

```
{"javascripts"=>[{"fo_global"=>["lazyload-min", "holla-min"]}]}
```

Comment: I agree, that's the wonderful about YAML - we can serialize something then read it back in later, so why not use that capability.

Comment: Ah, I was unaware that you could do that with a YAML file. Thanks so much!

Comment: For some reason, I can require yaml, but I get a parse error, then I see something about Psych. Then when I do Psych.load("file.yml"), it just outputs the "file.yml" part and not the actual contents of the file.

Comment: Huh, it was because I was using tabs. It seems that it only wants spaces instead of tabs, and then throws all sorts of errors.

Comment: What is the difference between #load and #load_file in YAML library?

Comment: `YAML.load` takes a YAML string, `YAML.load_file` takes a relative file path.

Comment: The `load_file` method does not exist according to the docs of [YAML](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML.html). This method as well as others, are documented over [here](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych.html). I found out which version of Psych is included with Ruby over on [this site](https://stdgems.org/psych/). lol seriously Ruby, you need to get your shit together - like literally.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem but also wanted to get the content of the file (after the YAML front-matter).

This is the best solution I have found:

```
if (md = contents.match(/^(?<metadata>---\s*\n.*?\n?)^(---\s*$\n?)/m))
  self.contents = md.post_match
  self.metadata = YAML.load(md[:metadata])
end
```

Source and discussion: https://practicingruby.com/articles/tricks-for-working-with-text-and-files

Comment: Link now seems to be https://practicingruby.com/articles/tricks-for-working-with-text-and-files

Comment: Thanks @devstuff - I have updated the link in the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the one liner i use, from terminal, to test the content of yml file(s):

```
$ ruby  -r yaml -r pp  -e 'pp YAML.load_file("/Users/za/project/application.yml")'
{"logging"=>
  {"path"=>"/var/logs/",
   "file"=>"TacoCloud.log",
   "level"=>
    {"root"=>"WARN", "org"=>{"springframework"=>{"security"=>"DEBUG"}}}}}
```