# Remove sensitive information from a Rakefile

Tags: ruby, git, rakefile

What are the recommended procedures for removing sensitive information from a Rakefile?

For example, my project's Rakefile looks like:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
$:.unshift("/Library/RubyMotion/lib")
require 'motion/project'
require 'bubble-wrap'

Motion::Project::App.setup do |app|
  # Use `rake config' to see complete project settings.
  app.name = 'App Name'
  app.codesign_certificate  = 'iPhone Developer: Name Goes Here (12SELC3456)'
end
```

Since `app.codesign_certificate  = 'iPhone Developer: Name Goes Here (12SELC3456)'` doesn't pertain to other contributers of the project, I'd like to remove it before committing my code to source control.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a better answer than "remove the information before committing". I know of no automated procedure for determining which information is sensitive.

Comment: Keith Thompson: I'm more of looking for a way to automatically remove specified information from files before committing. To manually remove the information, commit, then put it back is tedious.

Comment: How about you do all your work on a branch and just never merge the sensitive stuff to the main branch (the branch that gets pushed)?

Comment: But if someone forget and merge? Human can miss something sometimes. I would go for like a "git config" file, that you enter every personal information and never would be committed, because it is on a igone list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting that info in other file, for instance an YML, and referencing it on your Rakefile? The YML would be on you .gitignore to avoid committing personal information.

Example of .YML file:

```
app:
  codesign_certificate: "iPhone Developer: Name Goes Here (12SELC3456)"
```

**EDIT**

For more info how to read an YML file: [How do I parse a YAML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877004/how-do-i-parse-a-yaml-file)

Comment: That'll do. My originally question was looking for a language agnostic way to remove sensitive information from files before committing them, but I've changed it since.

Comment: Sorry @zachlatta, I didn't think as an agnostic solution =/

Comment: I've found something that would be at least interesting as an agnostic solution: You could have a pre-commit hook, that you could run some script to search for sensitive fields or strings inside your files (http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)