# Strange Ruby scoping issue (I think)

Tags: ruby, vagrant

I have only minimal knowledge of Ruby, but I am working on a Vagrant VM for my office. I have the settings configured in variables to allow for easy customizing by each of our developers, but I am running into problems when I try to include the variables from an outside file.

Here is the basic gist of what I am doing (this works):

```
# Local (host) system info
host_os = "Windows"
nfs_enabled = false

# IP and Port Configuration
vm_ip_address = "33.33.33.10"
vm_http_port = 80
host_http_port = 8888
vm_mysql_port = 3306
host_mysql_port = 3306   # Warning, mysql port configuration using 3306 will interfere with any locally run MySQL server.
local_sites_path = "D:\\Web"
vm_sites_path = ENV["HOME"] + "/Sites"

# VM Configuration
vm_memory = "1024"

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  ... do vagrant stuff here
```

However, this does not work (the contents of config.local.rb match the variable declarations above):

```
if(File.file?("config.local.rb"))
  require_relative 'config.local.rb'
else
  # Local (host) system info
  host_os = "Mac"
  nfs_enabled = true

  # IP and Port Configuration
  vm_ip_address = "33.33.33.10"
  vm_http_port = 80
  host_http_port = 8888
  vm_mysql_port = 3306
  host_mysql_port = 3306   # Warning, mysql port configuration using 3306 will interfere with any locally run MySQL server.
  local_sites_path = ENV["HOME"] + "/Sites"
  vm_sites_path = ENV["HOME"] + "/Sites"

  # VM Configuration
  vm_memory = "512"
end

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  ... do vagrant stuff here
```

Any ideas what is happening here? In both cases, the variable declarations are at the top of the file, so my understanding is that they should be in the global scope.

Here is the contents of config.local.rb:

```
# Duplicate to config.local.rb to activate. Override the variables set in the Vagrantfile to tweak your local VM.

# Local (host) system info
host_os = "Windows"
nfs_enabled = false

# IP and Port Configuration
vm_ip_address = "33.33.33.10"
vm_http_port = 80
host_http_port = 8888
vm_mysql_port = 3306
host_mysql_port = 3306   # Warning, mysql port configuration using 3306 will interfere with any locally run MySQL server.
local_sites_path = "D:\\Web"
vm_sites_path = ENV["HOME"] + "/Sites"

# VM Configuration
vm_memory = "1024"
```

As I said, I haven't really used Ruby before, but everything I know about programming and scope says that this should be working fine. I have checked (using `print` statements) that the file is being detected and included by the script, but for some reason it doesn't work unless I hard code the config settings directly in the Vagrantfile.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables starting with a lowercase letter are *local variables*. They are called "local" variables, because they are local to the scope they are defined in. In your case, they are local to the script body of `config.local.rb`. They cannot be accessed from anywhere else except the script body of `config.local.rb`. That's what makes them "local".

If you want a global variable, you need to use a global variable. Global variables start with a `$` sign.

Comment: Very delayed response, but this was the issue. I didn't realize that ruby's global variables needed the `$`.

Answer (score 0):

Jorg is correct in his explanation of local vs. global variables. Below is a possible alternative implementation that may do what you want it to do.

Declare your configuration in `config.local.rb` as a hash:

```
{
  host_os: "Windows",
  nfs_enabled: false
  # etc, etc.
}
```

In your other file:

```
if File.exist?("config.local.rb"))
  config = File.read("config.local.rb")
else
  config = {
    host_os: "Mac",
    nfs_enabled: true
    # etc, etc.
  }
end
```

Your `config` hash now has all your data.

If that approach looks like it may better suit your needs, then you should probably put the config data in a YAML file instead of a Ruby file: [How do I parse a YAML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877004/how-do-i-parse-a-yaml-file)