# Can I manipulate yaml files and write them out again

Tags: ruby, yaml

I have a map of values, the key is a filename and the value is an array strings.
I have the corresponding files

how would I load the file and create a fixed yaml value which contains the value of the array whether or not the value already exists

e.g.

YAML (file.yaml)

```
trg::azimuth:
-extra
-intra
-lateral
```

or

```
trg::azimuth: 
  [extra,intra,lateral]
```

from

RUBY

```
{"file.yaml" => ["extra","intra","lateral"]}
```

Comment: It's not real clear what you're trying to do. Where does `trg::azimuth:` come from? It's not in your sample hash, and not explained anywhere.

Comment: trg::azimuth: is a static value I expect to see in the yaml that will not change

Answer (score 1):

The [YAML documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML.html) doesn't cover its methods very well, but does say

> The underlying implementation is the libyaml wrapper Psych.

The [Psych documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych.html), which underlies YAML, covers reading, parsing, and emitting YAML.

Here's the basic process:

```
require 'yaml'

foo = {"file.yaml" => ["extra","intra","lateral"]}
bar = foo.to_yaml
# => "---\nfile.yaml:\n- extra\n- intra\n- lateral\n"
```

And here's what the generated, serialized `bar` variable looks like if written:

```
puts bar
# >> ---
# >> file.yaml:
# >> - extra
# >> - intra
# >> - lateral
```

That's the format a YAML parser needs:

```
baz = YAML.load(bar)
baz
# => {"file.yaml"=>["extra", "intra", "lateral"]}
```

At this point the hash has gone round-trip, from a Ruby hash, to a YAML-serialized string, back to a Ruby hash.

Writing YAML to a file is easy using Ruby's `File.write` method:

```
File.write(foo.keys.first, foo.values.first.to_yaml)
```

or

```
foo.each do |k, v| 
  File.write(k, v.to_yaml)
end
```

Which results in a file named "file.yaml", which contains:

```
---
- extra
- intra
- lateral
```

To read and parse a file, use YAML's [`load_file`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych.html#method-c-load_file) method.

```
foo = YAML.load_file('file.yaml')
# => ["extra", "intra", "lateral"]
```

"[How do I parse a YAML file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877004/how-do-i-parse-a-yaml-file)" might be of use, as well as the other "Related" links on the right side of this page.