# how to parse a yaml file?

Tags: ruby, yaml

I have a machine.yml file as follows:

```
---
    machines:  
     A:
        ip: ABC
        pass: vass
        user: A

     B:
        ip: XYZ
        pass: grass
        user: B

     C:
        ip: klm
        pass: pass
        user: C
```

I tried to parse the above file as follows:

```
        machines = YAML.load_file('machine.yml')
        machines = machines['machines']
        ## Iterate through entries in YAML file
        machines.each_value do |machines| 
           var = [machines["A"]["ip"], machines["A"]["pass"], machines["B"]["ip"],machines["B"]["pass"], machines["C"]["ip"],machines["C"]["pass"]]
           # var should have all the values 
        end
```

The "var" should contain all the values as a string. But I am not able execute the above piece as it's throwing errors. How can I parse all the values of YAML separately?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse a YAML file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877004/how-do-i-parse-a-yaml-file)

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 6):

## Your code

Since you hardcode the keys you're interested in, you don't need to iterate with `each_values` :

```
machines = YAML.load_file('machine.yml')
machines = machines['machines']
var = [machines["A"]["ip"], machines["A"]["pass"], machines["B"]["ip"],machines["B"]["pass"], machines["C"]["ip"],machines["C"]["pass"]]
```

## Alternative

First, you should try not to override the same variable every time (`machines`). It's called "shadowing", and it makes it harder to understand and use your code.

Depending on what you want to do, `each`, `map` or `flat_map` could help you :

```
require 'yaml'

yaml_hash = YAML.load_file('machine.yml')
p yaml_hash['machines']
#=> {"A"=>{"ip"=>"ABC", "pass"=>"vass", "user"=>"A"}, "B"=>{"ip"=>"XYZ", "pass"=>"grass", "user"=>"B"}, "C"=>{"ip"=>"klm", "pass"=>"pass", "user"=>"C"}}

yaml_hash['machines'].each do |letter, hash|
  p letter
  p hash['ip']
  p hash['pass']
end

#=>
# "A"
# "ABC"
# "vass"
# "B"
# "XYZ"
# "grass"
# "C"
# "klm"
# "pass"

p yaml_hash['machines'].values
#=> [{"ip"=>"ABC", "pass"=>"vass", "user"=>"A"}, {"ip"=>"XYZ", "pass"=>"grass", "user"=>"B"}, {"ip"=>"klm", "pass"=>"pass", "user"=>"C"}]

p yaml_hash['machines'].values.map { |hash| hash.values_at('ip', 'pass') }
#=> ["ABC", "vass"], ["XYZ", "grass"], ["klm", "pass"]]

p yaml_hash['machines'].values.flat_map { |hash| hash.values_at('ip', 'pass') }
#=> ["ABC", "vass", "XYZ", "grass", "klm", "pass"]
```

Comment: how to pass each value to a bash script i am doing as sample.sh, : args=>[p hash['ip']] but its not working.