# How can I configure my app to allow only specific emails to register with devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm setting up a CRUD feature and I only want a few people (entire email addresses) to be able to register through devise.

I've gone through countless posts but they mostly use email domains or single person login. I've also tried creating my own validation method in my User.rb but I can't seem to get it.

```
validate :check_email

  private

  def check_email
    @users = User.all

    if @users == '123.example@gmail.com')
        events_path
    else
        errors.add(:email, 'is not authorized')
    end
  end
```

I don't get an explicit error but the app seems to skip my 'if' condition and outputs the 'else' condition.

Comment: There's a missing `(` in the if statement.

Comment: You are checking `@users.all` against a single value `123.example@gmail.com`.  So at least you would need to use something like `includes?()` but don't you really need to validate this `before_save` on every attempt to sign up?  So perhaps a before save method that checks the email put in would work better?

Comment: Take a look here:: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-to:-Use-a-custom-email-validator-with-Devise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow only users with certain email addresses you could simply add an [*inclusion*](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#inclusion) validation.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  ALLOWED_EMAILS = %w[
    123.example@gmail.com
    456.example@gmail.com
    789.example@gmail.com
  ].freeze

  validates :email, inclusion: { in: ALLOWED_EMAILS, message: :invalid }

  # ...
end
```

You could also opt to load the `ALLOWED_EMAILS` from the settings or a file.

---

To [load from the Rails config](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#custom-configuration) you have to define the email addresses in a config file.

```
config.allowed_user_emails = %w[
  123.example@gmail.com
  456.example@gmail.com
  789.example@gmail.com
]
```

Then load them in the controller using:

```
ALLOWED_EMAILS = Rails.configuration.allowed_user_emails.freeze
```

---

To [load from for example a yaml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877004/how-do-i-parse-a-yaml-file) you could do something like:

```
ALLOWED_EMAILS = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('config', 'allowed_user_emails.yml')).freeze
```

Having the following in the file:

```
- 123.example@gmail.com
- 456.example@gmail.com
- 789.example@gmail.com
```

Comment: You can use a regular array if you don't like the [`%w[...]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Percent+Strings) notation, or somehow have spaces inside your email addresses.

Comment: Thank you! Your first chunk of code worked! I checked each of my email addresses along with invalid ones and it was a success! Also thank you to everyone else who offered help! I really appreciate it!

Comment: @SarahHumphreys Note that validation is only triggered when updating or creating new records. If you've already users in your database you can flush unwanted uses with a migration. `User.where.not(email: User::ALLOWED_EMAILS).delete_all` (or `destroy_all` if you need to trigger callbacks).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to accomplish this would be to create a custom validation like you did originally. In your user model you could create a validation that looks something like this:

```
validate :is_email_valid?


def is_email_valid
    if ["example@gmail.com", "example@yahoo.com", "123.example@gmail.com"].include?(self.email)
        errors.add :base, "Your email is not authorized for use!"
    end
end
```

This code will work when saving or creating a new record.

The problem with your code is that you are attempting to validate on a `ActiveRecord_Relation` object which cannot directly access validations for class instances. It's like trying to call an instance method from a class level; you have to validate one user at a time. You will want to execute validations on your object instance with a reference to `self`. So, looping through your users and then validating would work. Here is an example:

```
User.all.each do |i|

    if i.valid?
        puts "VALID"
    else
        puts "INVALID"
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I added the code you suggested to my user model and it worked for my first email address. I have three total addresses that I want to authorize. When I added those addresses to the 'if' condition and then went through the sign up form on my app,  I get this error: "undefined method `includes?' for "example.abc@gmail.com":String Did you mean? include?" .. If I make it 'include?' then I get the argument error "expecting 3, given 1.

Comment: I fixed my answer but the includes? function needs to be renamed to include?

Comment: still getting "wrong number of arguments (given 3, expected 1)". I do have commas between the three strings, should I remove those?

Comment: I updated my answer so that you can use an `array` to white-list your email addresses.

Comment: Now the app is letting me register any email I enter through the form on the webpage.  I'll keep at it and see what I can figure out. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Make sure your `create` function is `create!`. Also make sure you don't have a `!` in the if statement.

Answer (score -1):

Sarah,

The first step that I'd take in accomplishing this would be to work inside devise's registrations_controller. This is the controller where the signed up user will be served to and here you will want to over-write some of the Devise code. 
Ensure the controllers are created first by running Devise's controller generator:

```
rails generate devise:controllers users
```

Then you'll want to find the user's `registrations_controller.rb` and override the code in there under the create action. 
Here's an example of some code I wrote to override Devise's admin controller:

```
def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)
    # Below - If admin is coming from an email invite or shared invite link, grabs both token and workplace id from params.
    @token = params[:invite_token] if params[:invite_token]
    @workplace_id = params[:workplace_id] if params[:workplace_id]
    @workplace = Workplace.find(params[:workplace_id]) if params[:workplace_id] # Finds the workplace from the workplace_id, works for both invite email and shared link.
    @institute = @workplace.institute if params[:workplace_id]
    if @institute && @institute.has_super_admins?
      resource.super_admin = false
    end 

    if resource.save
      yield resource if block_given?
      if resource.persisted?
        if resource.active_for_authentication?
          # Below - If admin came from a shared workpalce invite link or email workplace invite
          if @token != nil # Admin signed up via a workplace invite email or the shared link
            # Below - Checks Payment plan for admins joining an institute to make sure the institute didn't exceed user count subscription permission.
            unless @institute.plan.unlimited_users? 
              if @institute.plan.user_count <= @institute.admins.count # Admin doesn't join workplace since institute has excited user allowance
                set_flash_message! :alert, :signed_up_no_workplace, :workplace => @workplace.name, :institute => @institute.name, :workplace_owner => @institute.subscription.admin.name
                sign_up(resource_name, resource)
                respond_with resource, location: institute_admin_path(resource.institute, resource)
              else # Admin successfully signs up and joins the workplace. Method is below in protected
                join_workplace_and_redirect
              end 
            else # Admin successfully signs up and joins the workplace. Method is below in protected
              join_workplace_and_redirect
            end
          else # Fresh admin signup
            sign_up(resource_name, resource)
            if resource.super_admin? # Checks if the admin is a super_admin and set as true, if so redirects to another page
              set_flash_message! :notice, :super_admin_signed_up, :name => resource.first_name
              respond_with resource, location: new_institute_path()
            else # Admin is not a super_admin and not first one who signed up inside a city. 
              set_flash_message! :notice, :admin_signed_up, :link => edit_institute_admin_path(resource.institute, resource), :city => resource.institute.name
              respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
            end 
          end
        else
          set_flash_message! :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}"
          expire_data_after_sign_in!
          respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
        end
      else
        flash[:alert] = "Your profile could not be created. See why below!"
        set_flash_message! :alert, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}"
        redirect_to request.referrer
      end
    else  # Failed to save
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource, location: new_admin_registration_path(workplace: @workplace)
    end
  end
```

To apply it to your case, what you may want to do is use a case statement to see if the email matches ones you want it to. For example, below you'll want to check the `resource` (the single user in this case, the user who is signing up) email attribute to determine whether it's a success or failure:

```
# Checks emails that are allowed
case resource.email 
when "123.example@gmail.com" 
  if resource.save # Success
    set_flash_message! :notice, :signup_succeed
    respond_with resource, location: home_page(resource)
  else # For some reason the allowed email didn't go through due to other validations
    set_flash_message! :alert, :signup_failure
    respond_with resource, location: new_user_path(resource)
  end 
else # Entered an email that is not allowed
  set_flash_message! :alert, :email_invalid
  respond_with resource, location: new_user_path(resource)
end
```

The `set_flash_message!` is Devises custom messages which can be edited in `config/locales/devise.en.yaml`. The second keyword refers to the name of the yaml key, and you can customize the error or success message in there. `respond_with` is the redirection and location. You can use as many `when` statements as needed. This is just one way to do it. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for such a thorough answer. I added the case statement to the registrations controller, but my app is still letting any email I enter in the webpage form register. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Haven't read the full answer, but that create method seems awfully complex for simply whitelisting a few email addresses.

Comment: It's true that below you can do a validation that would likely be simpler logic in the Model. The reason I included an override to Devise is due to the fact that later on, as your app grows (if it does) you may want to add more and more logic to overriding Devise via Controller, one reason Devise is a pain.

Comment: Using Cannon's logic below, add a line `return true` after the errors.add and see if that changes anything.

Comment: This answer is not very relevant to the original question.